# How do I stop Grab from creating new geometry?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, transforms

Blender 3.4

Select vertex, press "g" to Grab, move the mouse. I am expecting the vertex to be moved.

I get a new vertex , edges and faces created, linked to the selected vertex.

I have searched the Blender interface and google but cant find the answer.

[image: Selected Vertex]

[image]

I have used select all "a" and then  "m" to merge all by distance.

There are no modifiers associated with the object. There are no other meshes, that I can see. The vertex selected is a single vertex

Comment: This is certainly not expected. Is this an illusion created by a duplicate mesh, or, say , a modifier displaying its  result to you by having its 'cage' display set?

Comment: Press `A` to select all, then `M` > _Merge_ > _By Distance_. If it still behaves like this, the question would be if there are any modifiers etc. added to the object as Robin mentioned, since you gave us zero information on your mesh/object.

Comment: Yes I have done this, added two screenshots, showing the mesh and the selected vertex, grabbing it and moving the mouse, creates new geometry. It didn't do this when I started this model.

Comment: Check `Edit > Preferences… > Keymap` and in the search bar select `KeyBinding` and search for `G` just to make sure there isn't a rogue keybind for `Mesh > Duplicate` (or some other duplicate something).

Comment: Grab operator does not create any geometry. There must be double geometry or maybe you accidentally pressed something else like f that creates the exact geometry as you show in the screenshots with F2 addon enabled. F and G are close to each other - maybe the keyboard is faulty.

Comment: Also when doing merge by distance, confirm the operation and then in F9 menu slide the `Merge Distance` up and make sure that the `Removed 0 vertice(s)` message on the bottom of the screen does not change until you start losing actual vertices. When I create a model like you did (only edges and vertices) and then duplicate the model and move it by 0.001, I can't tell that it's 2 models and the default merge distance of 0.0001 doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help, it is to do with the Merge by distance, leaving some extra double edges.

Viewed in Object-mode the problem mesh looks awful with missing edges.

Using merge by distance, and changing the distance to 0.01, fixes most of it. But I had to delete some edges, which were if fact still double edges, even tho' the vertices at the ends were singles. After this manual fixing, Grab now works as expected.

Thanks all